# Is this copyright information sufficient for distributing theme files?

Tags: beamer, copyright

I need to distribute theme files to several colleagues, and the templates I'm working off of all have this header:

```
Copyright year by name <email>

This file may be distributed and/or modified

1. under the LaTeX Project Public License and/or
2. under the GNU Public License.

See the file doc/licenses/LICENSE for more details.
```

I read through the Beamer manual's copyright section, am I interpreting it correctly that this is all I need to include in the file?

EDIT:

Since the theme files don't have to be placed in the LaTeX distribution location (they'll also work in the compiling directory) I wanted to clear that last line up some.  I was going to specify a more specific path, but it turns out I can't find the correct doc/licenses/* files either.  Looking at [LICENSE](http://mirror.math.ku.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/licenses/LICENSE) which I found on what looks like [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/licenses), none of the other files are there.  I can't find `manifest-code.txt`, I can't find `manifest-documentation.txt`, and I can't find the plain text version of the license.  I can't even find that directory in either of the LaTeX distributions I have access to.  Since I know the license is in the Beamer manual, I'll just direct to that with

```
See the Section 'Licenses and Copyright' in the Beamer manual for more details.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

personally, i would be happy with that, except i don't know where
doc/licenses/LICENSE would live -- it had better be something relative to
where the licence statement lives.  subject to that, it would pass the
ctan catalogue checks.

note that the ctan catalogue only ever lists a single licence.  which one
gets chosen to appear in the catalogue page for the package is up to the
ctan team member who gets to write the catalogue entry.

Comment: ah, good point.  i'd be distributing this via email to my department, and while my colleagues would have the ability to either place it in their latex distribution (where `doc` is), they'd also be able to just place it in the directory where they're compiling.  maybe i should clear that last line up.